# What's the difference between using @Transactional and Spring template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I use @Transactional in my DAO will all of my EntityManager queries be encapsulated with commit and close?  Or do I need to use Spring template (JPA template, Hibernate template)?  What's the difference between using @Transactional and Spring template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between using annotation-based transaction demarcation (`@Transactional`) and the `TransactionTemplate` is that `TransactionTemplate` couples you to Spring's transaction infrastructure and means that you will programmatically handle setting the transaction status if the transaction should be rolled back.  You can use annotation-based transaction demarcation with the Spring transaction support or with AspectJ transactions outside of a Spring container.

See also the [online documentation for transactions in Spring](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html).

Answer (score 4):

The Spring template classes are only there to provide a nicer API for doing persistence operations - they do not deal with transactions. If you want to have transactional operations, you either need to use the @Transactional annotation approach, or use TransactionTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

When you use @transactional with the proper Spring configuration, Spring will recognize that the method needs an transaction and will handle the transaction creation, commit and close for you.

Like skaffman said, @transactional is not directly tied to the template classes. They can be used for any class that may need transactions.