# when using @transactional do i need to use jpatemplate/hibernatetemplate?

Tags: java, spring

when using @transactional do i need to use jpatemplate/hibernatetemplate ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877018/different-using-transactional-and-spring-template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't.  Spring has a built-in transaction manager that can be used for simple transactions, e.g. if you don't need to track transactions across more than one DataSource.  The configuration should be as simple as this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Where the bean named "dataSource" is some DataSource bean configured elsewhere in your XML file.

However if you're using JPA or Hibernate, it would be a good idea to use the JPATransactionManager or HibernateTransactionManager, respectively.

If you really wanted to you could also use JTA, which is Sun's standard transaction implementation.  I think the spring class is called JTATransactionManager.

Using transaction managers other than Spring's out-of-the-box one (the one defined in the XML config above) will give you the ability to use transactions across multiple DataSources.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the what version of Hibernate you are using. With later versions the simple answer is no you don't need the templates. See here for a comprehensive discussion:

http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/

Answer (score 1):

I came across an article that explains the process of implementing TxManager using @Transactional in depth. If you are interested, you can check [this article](http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-use-transaction-manager-with.html) here. I tried and this works!